# proving the given random variable a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Let $T>0$ and $\{\mathcal{F_s}\}_{s\in[0,T]}$ be a filtration on the space $\Omega$. Define,$$T' = \sum_{n=0}^k\,t_n\,1_{X_n}\,,$$ where $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_k=T$ and $\{X_n\}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ and $X_n\in \mathcal{F_{t_n}}$ for all $n$.

I want to prove that $T'$ is $\{\mathcal{F_s}\}$ stopping time. i.e: $\{T'=s\}\in \mathcal{F_s} $ for all $s\in[0,T]$.

Let $s$ be fixed and define $T_n = t_n1_{X_n}$ for each $n$. I think it suffices to prove that $T_n$ is $\mathcal{F_s}$ m'ble but not sure how to proceed. Any hint on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of stopping time applies to discrete case but here you have the continuous case. The definition is $\{T'\leq s\} \in \mathcal F_s$ for all $s$. Verify that $\{T'\leq s\}=\bigcup_I X_n$ where $I=\{n: t_n \leq s\}$. Note that$X_n \in \mathcal F_{t_n} \subseteq \mathcal F_s$ for any $n$ with $t_n \leq s$. Hence  $\{T'\leq s\} \in \mathcal F_s$.